# Передвижение по svg-путям

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, path

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример реализации передвижения по path нескольких объектов (у меня они нарисованы в canvas,это массив из 10-ти банальных particles, не могу добиться передвижения с расстоянием между друг-другом - летают по path одним комком..), спасибо.

Comment: Выкладывайте хотя бы часть кода, а иначе всё что вы написали ровняется null. 

Могу только посоветовать библиотеку greensock для анимации контента и svg, вроде не плохо работает